# Docker run override entrypoint with shell script which accepts arguments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have entrypoint shell script which accepts arguments **-a -b**.

I have working **docker-compose.yml** file where I override tomcat's entrypoint with instruction:

```
entrypoint: /usr/local/tomcat/entrypoint.sh -a param1 -b param2
```

What is **docker run** alternative?

```
docker run --entrypoint "/usr/local/tomcat/entrypoint.sh -a param1 -b param2" tomcat:jre8
```

does not work

I get:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: 
invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: 
starting container process caused \"exec:
\\\"/usr/local/tomcat/entrypoint.sh -a param1 -b param2\\\": 
stat /usr/local/tomcat/entrypoint.sh -a param1 -b param2: 
no such file or directory\"\n".
```

FYI:

```
docker run --entrypoint "/usr/local/tomcat/entrypoint.sh" tomcat:jre8
```

works from Docker point of view, but obviously script fails

Answer (score 164, accepted):

It is because of the quotes you're using around your command.

When you run `docker run --entrypoint "/usr/local/tomcat/entrypoint.sh -a param1 -b param2" tomcat:jre8` Docker treats whatever is within those quotes as a single script file.

As you can see from the error:

```
stat /usr/local/tomcat/entrypoint.sh -a param1 -b param2: 
no such file or directory\"\n".
```

It's trying to perform a `stat` on the file before running it, so it knows if it exists.

Place the arguments to your entrypoint at the end of your docker command like so:

```
docker run --entrypoint <entrypoint.sh> <image:tag> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>
```

Your command becomes:

```
docker run --entrypoint /usr/local/tomcat/entrypoint.sh tomcat:jre8 -a param1 -b param2
```

Have a look at the code snippets in the official documentation:

> The ENTRYPOINT of an image is similar to a COMMAND because it
>   specifies **what executable to run** when the container starts

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime

Comment: just to clarify (order DOES matter) - after `run` and not at the end of the command..

Comment: Example: `docker run -it --entrypoint sh your-image-repository:18457/example/report:8ba2ca9_RC`

Comment: To clarify, this is not overriding only the entrypoint, as webofmars' answer indicates, it's overriding the entrypoint and the commands.  For the specific question asked though, that's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 35):

I think this is also worth noting:

### If you have a bunch of arguments to your `docker run` command, your `--entrypoint` should come first.

I don't know which of my arguments was the problem, but putting `--entrypoint "/bin/bash"` at the end did not prevent execution of the ENTRYPOINT from the Dockerfile. My arguments included:

- 1x --rm
- 1x --name
- 1x -it
- 3x -v
- 6x -p
- 4x -e

Comment: based on docker documentation this is why - docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...] - It's an OPTION

Answer (score 11):

*N.B: Answering this old question because the proposed answer are not satisfying me as they are partly wrong.*

**Short answer:**
There is no way to override the entrypoint with multiples arguments but you can move them to the command (part after the image name) that will work

---

**More detailed answer:**

After some testing and reading the docs it's obvious that there is no way to mimic the dockerfile or docker-compose entrypoint behavior with docker run.

The proposed answers are overriding the entrypoint to a single binary (i.e. without args) and putting the originals arguments to the COMMAND.

That is often doing the job but there is really a conceptual difference that you can reveal using `docker inspect`.

In docker, ENTRYPOINT is the binary + the default args that will be launched at startup and that are not supposed to be changed by the user at normal use. COMMAND are the remaining arguments or parameters that you want user to change (ex: the targeted hostname of ping).So they are conceptually different.

Saying that in many case this is not a matter to move args from entrypoint to command for a one time container the resulting command will look the same.

Answer (score -1):

Example - copy terraform to /$USER/.local/bin use new entrypoint `/bin/sh` and arguments for this entrypoint as `-c "cp /bin/terraform /app"`

```
docker run --rm --name terraform --entrypoint "/bin/sh" -v /$USER/.local/bin:/app hashicorp/terraform:latest -c "cp /bin/terraform /app"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).