# Docker container don't hot reloads with nodemon on express app

Tags: node.js, docker, containers, nodemon

Nodemon doesn't reload container content

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app


COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install

COPY . .

USER node

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

My express application:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Testing application!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('test')
})
```

I expect that nodemon reloads the container content with bind volume.

My container:

```
docker container run -p 3000:3000 -v ${pwd}:/app -v /app/node_modules --name expapp expresstestappimage nodemon server.js
```

Comment: try adding --legacy-watch and see if it reloads

Comment: Do you actually need Docker for this use case; can you run `nodemon` directly on the host system, discarding the first 3/4 of that command line?

Answer (score 0):

You need here to override the entrypoint.

Use ‘--entrypoint’ option to do so.

Using the ‘--entrypoint’ your example will be look like

```
docker container run -p 3000:3000 -v ${pwd}:/app -v /app/node_modules --name expapp —-entrypoint <path-to-nodemon-executable> expresstestappimage <path-to-your-server.js>
```

Reference:

1. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41699330/2143128