# How to override entrypoint arguments of Azure Pipelines service container without creating custom image?

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

There is a [service container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/service-containers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), which I want to be UP while my pipeline is running.

```yaml
resources:
  containers:
  - container: my_service
    image: dockerhub-service-image:1.0.0

services:
  my_service: my_service
```

I need to slightly override it's default startup configuration, so I have to somehow add custom arguments for `ENTRYPOINT` command.

The problem is that it seems like there is no way to override `CMD` of an image using `$resources.containers` section of Azure Pipelines yaml. By looking at Azure [yaml spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-containers-container?view=azure-pipelines), I can only see that there is an `options` available, which can help me to override `ENTRYPOINT` by passing custom value to `--entrypoint=` of `docker start`. This could be the solution of my problem, because [Dockerfile's `ENTRYPOINT` supports "exec form"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), which can include command+multiple arguments in `Dockerfile`s like this:

```
FROM alpine/curl
ENTRYPOINT ["curl" , "http://example.com/" ]
```

If `--entrypoint=` could help me to override `ENTRYPOINT` exec form, it would solve my problem. But I have no idea how to define **exec form** value with `--entrypoint=` cmd line option, and one of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62728758/3581539 says that: "There is no way to override the entrypoint with multiples arguments", so I am stuck here. Is it indeed impossible to accept **exec form** for `--entrypoint=`?

If `--entrypoint=` can't help me here, is there any other way to override `ENTRYPOINT` argument of `services` container in Azure Pipelines without preparing a custom image?

Answer (score 0):

I can give my 2 cents on this:

> If --entrypoint= can't help me here, is there any other way to override ENTRYPOINT argument of services container in Azure Pipelines without preparing a custom image?

I have a similar requirement to use a single image for multiple customers without building an image for each customer. Here is my solution:

I have created a shell script that acts as my entry point. In your case, the `Docker` file must be changed to:

```
RUN chmod +x /startup.sh

ENTRYPOINT /startup.sh
CMD "run"
```

I'll assume that you can deal with the script location.

The shell script will contain:

```
#!/bin/sh

// Where the $$YOUR_ARGUMENT_HERE is an env variable you set in the YAML manifest.
curl $YOUR_ARGUMENT_HERE
```

Then, finally, the YAML file should look like this.
I just took the default YAML file from the service container link you provided and cut the irrelevant bits.

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - 8080:80
    env:
      NGINX_PORT: 80
      YOUR_ARGUMENT_HERE: "www.google.com"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this forces me to build at least one custom image anyway, while I do not want to build anything and I only want to take an existing image from Docker Hub